# Excel VBA Case doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, case

```
Public Function Test(y As Double)
Select Case y  
Case y = 0           //problem starts here
Test= "No value"     // problem ends here

Case Else
s = 0
For i = 1 To 3
s = s + 20 / y
Next
Test= s
End Select
End Function
```

When the y=0 the result I get is "#Value!" what is the problem here. When y is not 0 everything works.

Comment: For completeness you could also use the syntax 'Case Is = 0' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using case incorrectly, you are not supposed to say `y=0` just say `case 0` or `case "0"`

Else part works because every value including 0 goes to the same case.

```
Public Function Test(y As Double)
  Select Case y  
    Case  "0"         // This is the correct way to use it     
      Test= "No value"     

    Case Else
      s = 0
      For i = 1 To 3
        s = s + 20 / y
      Next
      Test= s
  End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function test(y As Double)
    Select Case y
        Case 0
            test = "doesnt exist"

        Case Else
            s=0
            For i = 1 To 10
            s=y/(i^1)
            Next
            test = s

    End Select
End Function
```

You are using = in your case check which is wrong.  You should use it as

```
Case testValue
    Do something here
```

If it is a string then put it in quotes

```
Case "Hello World"
    do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want

```
Case 0
```

Instead of

```
Case y = 0
```

Your code will only execute the latter if y has a value of (True/False).